# What does @ (at symbol) do in Swift?

Tags: swift

When I create a new swift iOS project in Xcode, I see

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Due to the way Google search seems to work, searching for programming help on the '@' symbol seems rather difficult...

Is it a shorthand for applying a decorator like in Python? i.e. is UIApplicationMain a function that accepts a single class argument, and classes are first class objects in Swift?

Comment: Note that you *can* search for `@` in the Swift Programming Language iBook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The @... represents an attribute, from SWIFT documentation:

> Attributes provide more information about a declaration or type. There
>   are two kinds of attributes in Swift, those that apply to declarations
>   and those that apply to types.
>
> You specify an attribute by writing the @ symbol followed by the
>   attribute’s name and any arguments that the attribute accepts:

You can read about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html).